# Why is the type of the first argument in Redux middleware `MiddlewareAPI` and not `Store`?

Tags: typescript, redux

In the examples and as far as I've used it for years, I assumed the first function took a store object... yet I'm seeing many example of people typing it with `MiddlewareAPI` and in fact the redux code shows this as well.

Why would the middleware type it as `Store`? Is it because it is instead only part of a store? What even is it? Why isn't it named something like `StoreHandler` instead of something as generic as `MiddlewareAPI`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the complete definition of a store is `{dispatch, getState, subscribe, replaceReducer}`, and middleware are not allowed to subscribe or replace reducers.  Therefore, they are passed an object that represents a *subset* of the store API: `{dispatch, getState}`.

[The actual Redux TS types refer to that as `MiddlewareAPI`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/8aca937f695997e979bf8c0e03dbf22a2bf284dc/index.d.ts#L341-L365), not `Store`:

```
export interface MiddlewareAPI<D extends Dispatch = Dispatch, S = any> {
  dispatch: D
  getState(): S
}

export interface Middleware<
  DispatchExt = {},
  S = any,
  D extends Dispatch = Dispatch
> {
  (api: MiddlewareAPI<D, S>): (
    next: Dispatch<AnyAction>
  ) => (action: any) => any
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!

How about "Why isn't it named something like StoreHandler instead of something as generic as MiddlewareAPI?" That's obviously more open ended though.

Comment: A) I didn't create the names of the types - you'd really have to ask the folks who wrote the original TS type definitions.  B) `StoreHandler` doesn't sound meaningful at all, and really seems wrong.  It's not the "store", and there's no "handling" going on.  `MiddlewareAPI` isn't entirely descriptive, but at least it indicates that it's something specific to middleware.  I personally tend to name the variable `storeAPI` when I'm writing a middleware.

Comment: `storeAPI` is the best name i've heard thus far. Thanks!